# How to remove optional peer dependency from NPM project?

Tags: npm, peer-dependencies

I am participating in building a webapp that used to use `node-sass`. We migrated to `sass` in the meantime but we have still `node-sass` in our `package-lock.json`. I want to fix that.

In the beginning, we had something like this

```
$ npm ls node-sass
cookbook@0.9.13 /home/private/Documents/Projekte/nextcloud-apps/nextcloud-app-dev/volumes/custom_apps/cookbook
├── node-sass@7.0.1
└─┬ sass-loader@13.0.2
  └── node-sass@7.0.1 deduped
```

OK, lets remove the dependency by calling `npm uninstall node-sass`. The result is

```
$ npm ls node-sass
cookbook@0.9.13 /home/private/Documents/Projekte/nextcloud-apps/nextcloud-app-dev/volumes/custom_apps/cookbook
└─┬ sass-loader@13.0.2
  └── node-sass@7.0.1
```

I do not get the reason, why `sass-loader` is still depending on `node-sass`. OK, let's have a closer look:

```
$ npm why node-sass
node-sass@7.0.1 optional peer
node_modules/node-sass
  peerOptional node-sass@"^4.0.0 || ^5.0.0 || ^6.0.0 || ^7.0.0" from sass-loader@13.0.2
  node_modules/sass-loader
    sass-loader@"^13.0.2" from the root project
    peer sass-loader@"^13.0.1" from @nextcloud/webpack-vue-config@5.3.0
    node_modules/@nextcloud/webpack-vue-config
      dev @nextcloud/webpack-vue-config@"^5.0.0" from the root project
```

Now I am a bit surprised. The package `node-sass` is only installed as a peer dependency. So, why is it installed at all? I thought the idea of peer dependencies is to allow for the root project to select the version in use.

Also, it is only optional. So, it should be able to remove it (eventually there might be a warning during removal but nothing serious).

I am not working on the `@nextcloud/webpack-vue-config` package. It is a mere dev dependency of the webapp. So, NPM should not install the `node-sass` as a dev dependency on any of my dependencies.

**How can I remove the `node-sass` package from my project's `package-lock.json`?** It is still anchored in the `package-lock.json` and thus installed on each build.

I could use the `--no-optional` CLI option of `npm` to skip over *all* optional dependencies. I do not want to do that. The "problem" with this is that the GitHub dependency checker will not consider the `node-sass` module as skipped and continue complaining. Also, other optional dependencies might be skipped as well, although we would like to have them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I ran into this with node-sass and sass-loader the other day.

Easy solve for me was to remove `@nextcloud/webpack-vue-config` from my package.json, do an `npm install` then put it back and rerun `npm install`

that was enough to get the internals reset to make node-sass go away.